# Supernatural Stamina & Vehicles

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I crew a Vehicle to block. Once it's a creature, I cast [Supernatural Stamina](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSupernatural%20Stamina%5d), targeting the Vehicle. Text for Supernatural Stamina:

> Until end of turn, target creature gets +2/+0 and gains "Whenever this creature dies, return it to the battlefield tapped under its owner's control."

If my Vehicle dies, does it return to the battlefield because it met its trigger by dying, or does it remain in the graveyard because the effect checks for a creature, and it's an artifact in the graveyard? If it does return, does it return as a creature until end of turn, or as an uncrewed vehicle?

Comment: Hi Pie, and welcome to the site! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you can join us in [chat].

Answer (score 8):

Your vehicle will return to the battlefield, uncrewed and not a creature.

The first part is because of [rule 201.5](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Name):

> 201.5. If an ability of an object uses a phrase such as “this [something]” to identify an object, where [something] is a characteristic, it is referring to that particular object, even if it isn’t the appropriate characteristic at the time.

Supernatural Stamina is using "this creature" as a flavorful alternative to "this object". :)

Meanwhile, it returns as an ordinary uncrewed vehicle because of [rule 400.7](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Zone):

> An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule: *[None of these exceptions apply here.]*

Once it returns to the battlefield, it has absolutely nothing to do with the previous crewed vehicle object that was represented by that same card. It's a brand new vehicle.

Comment: Re "*as a flavorful alternative to "this whatever-it-is"*", as a flavorful alternative to "this object".

Comment: "*There are nine exceptions to this rule*" Yup. That's why we love MTG.